# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un salto de línea a esta variación con repetición?

Tags: python, itertools

Estoy estudiando la comprensión de ciclos y la parte de combinaciones en python para poder combinar diferentes números con letras. En este caso estoy haciendo una combinatoria donde sí importa el orden, sí se toman todos los elementos y sí hay repeticiones: **n^r**. Así que trato de guardar el archivo con un salto de línea, pero no consigo que ocurra:

```
archivo.write([p for p in product(x, repeat=2)+str('\n')])
```

¿Hay alguna forma de corregir este error?

Código completo:

```
from itertools import product
archivo=open('NumerosVariados.txt', 'w')
x = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
archivo.write('\n'+str([p for p in product(x, repeat=2)]))
archivo.close()
```

De antemano muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que has llegado a una secuencia y la quieres guardar en un fichero, lo primero sería convertirla en líneas de texto:

```py
lineas = [str(p)+'\n' for p in product(x, repeat=2)]
```

Por lo que interpreto, lo que quieres es obtener números hexadecimales de dos dígitos. Del `product()` lo que obtienes son tuplas que habría que *aplanar* con `.join()` para que fueran cadenas. Algo así:

```py
lineas = ["".join(p)+'\n' for p in product(x, repeat=2)]
```

Para guardar estas líneas con `.write()`, podemos seguir *aplanando* para crear una cadena o, mejor, usar el método `.writelines()`:

```py
archivo.writelines(lineas)
```

Recomponiendo un poco tu código, quedaría así:

```py
from itertools import product
from string import hexdigits

with open('NumerosVariados.txt', 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.writelines("".join(p)+'\n' for p in product(hexdigits, repeat=2))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!